# Retrieve a value from object in perl

Tags: perl, web, fastcgi, cpan, mod-perl

I am getting

```
$VAR1 = bless( \*{'Fh::fh00001Screenshot.png'}, 'Fh' );
```

in a variable. But I need to retrieve `fh00001Screenshot.png` from it. How can I get it?

Comment: It looks like you are using a module, in which case it is best to check the documentation for the proper way to do it.

Comment: We really need to see the code you are running. It looks to me like you are using Data::Dumper to dump an object which is a blessed typeglob ref. This probably isn't what you want to do.

Comment: Hafsal, I have read the many recent questions you have asked and I think you misunderstand what role StackOverflow serves. This site is for specific programming issues, in which you show us some code and we try to help you fix it. Without showing us your code, you either (1) don't give us enough to work with or (2) are asking us to do your job for you. Please read the [faq] and in the future please submit questions that are more in line with the goals of this site.

Answer (score 4):

The `Fh` package is used internally by the [`CGI`](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI) module to handle temporary files used for building multipart data. You shouldn't be using it directly.

Check carefully to make sure there is no better way before using this code which comes from the `CGI` code for `Fh::asString`

```
(my $name = $$VAR1) =~ s/^\*(\w+::fh\d{5})+//; 
print $name;
```

**output**

```
Screenshot.png
```

**Update**

Rather than picking bits out of the `CGI` code, it looks like this package - which should really be a private one - is accessible from calling code. Use just `$var->asString` instead, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

my $var = do {
  no strict 'refs';
  my $var = bless( \*{'Fh::fh00001Screenshot.png'}, 'Fh' );
};

print $var->asString;
```